# Can the else clause be simplified in this if\else ladder?

Tags: c++, if-statement, visual-c++, c++20

I have this`else` clause:

```
else if (iItemIndex == 1 || iItemIndex == 3 || iItemIndex== 5 || iItemIndex == 7 ||
    iItemIndex == 10 || iItemIndex == 12 || iItemIndex == 14 || iItemIndex == 16 ||
    iItemIndex == 19 || iItemIndex == 21 || iItemIndex == 23 || iItemIndex == 25)
```

Can it be simplified in some way? Nothing wrong with the code. Just curious if there is a less verbose way of doing the test. In context I have:

```
if(iItemIndex == 0 || iItemIndex == 9 || iItemIndex == 18)
{
    // Do something
}
else if (iItemIndex == 1 || iItemIndex == 3 || iItemIndex== 5 || iItemIndex == 7 ||
    iItemIndex == 10 || iItemIndex == 12 || iItemIndex == 14 || iItemIndex == 16 ||
    iItemIndex == 19 || iItemIndex == 21 || iItemIndex == 23 || iItemIndex == 25)
{
    // Do something else
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: You could try making an array with those vals and then have a condition to find `itemIndex`
```
if (std::find(std::begin(ourArray), std::end(ourArray), 99) != std::end(ourArray))
{
 // stuffz
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
const bool rng=i>=0 && i<27;
if(const auto r=i%9; rng && !r) …
else if(rng && (r&1)) …
else …
```

This can of course be much simplified if the value may be assumed to be in the relevant **range**:

```
if(const auto r=i%9; !r) …
else if(r&1) …
else …
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this use of IF where you seem to be creating a variable and then testing that variable at the same time.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: It’s a C++17 feature, but it’s just a convenience.  You could declare the variables outside just as well.